# Error importing Azure Synapse database into Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure, azure-synapse

I need to connect Azure Synapse database to Azure DevOps for deploy it to my production environment. To do it I need to link Synapse database to Git within Visual Studio using a SQL Server Database project. I'm using VS 2017 and I'm getting the following error: "The server version or database compatibility level is not supported".

What does it means? How can avoid it?

Import Synapse database to Visual Studio issue:

[image: Import Synapse database to Visual Studio issue]

Comment: As far as I know, VS2017 / SSDT for VS 2017 had no support for Synapse databases.

Answer (score 0):

> Using SSDT for VS 2017- Azure Synapse Analytics (supports queries only; database projects aren't yet supported).

I would suggest you to use SSDT for VS 2019.

Visual Studio 2019 SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) is a single tool allowing you to do the following:

- Connect, query, and develop applications
- Leverage an object explorer to visually explore all objects in your data model including tables, views, stored procedures, and etc.
- Generate T-SQL data definition language (DDL) scripts for your objects
- Develop your data warehouse using a state-based approach with SSDT Database Projects
- Integrate your database project with source control systems such as Git with Azure Repos
- Set up continuous integration and deployment pipelines with automation servers such as Azure DevOps

**Reference:** [Getting started with Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-install-visual-studio) and [New in Azure Synapse Analytics: CICD for SQL Analytics using SQL Server Data Tools](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/11/07/new-in-azure-synapse-analytics-cicd-for-sql-analytics-using-sql-server-data-tools/)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: This is fine for data warehouses in Synapse and works well. However using VS2019 for Synapse Serverless SQL Database does not work, build errors occur when you are using the documented syntax as specified: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-cosmos-db-analytical-store?tabs=openrowset-key.  There is no option in the solution properties to target a Synapse Serverless database, hence VS gives build errors.